# Serverless offline start error due to MongoDB connection string

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, mongodb-atlas

I am testing a REST API locally. The beginning of my serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
service: aws-lambda-api-service
variablesResolutionMode: 20210326
frameworkVersion: '2'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    MONGODB_URI: ${file(./config.js):fetchMongoUrl}
```

When I run `sls offline start --skipCacheInvalidation` it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
    - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.MONGODB_URI": Source "file" returned not supported result: "undefined"
```

The config.js file is in the root directory and looks as follows:

```
module.exports.fetchMongoUrl = () => {
    // create / fetch dynamic data here (e.g. call an API)
    return process.env.MONGODB_URI;
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: isn't this cyclic ? ENV var is fetching from the file, but the function in the file is pointing to the ENV. Where exactly are you configuring the actual URL?

Comment: the uri is declared in the .env file.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new file named as `config.json` & put `MONGODB_URI` value this way:

```
{
  "MONGODB_URI": "the uri of mongodb server"
}
```

Also modify your serverless.yml file.

```
environment:
    MONGODB_URI: ${file(config.json):MONGODB_URI}
```